Laravel and Redis configuration: `SELECT` failed: ERR invalid DB index
My .env:
CACHE_DRIVER=redis2 
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
MODEL_CACHE_ENABLED=true
MODEL_CACHE_STORE=redis2
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_CACHE_DB=0

My cache.php:
        'redis2' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache2',
            'lock_connection' => 'default',
        ],

My database.php:
       'cache2' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '0'),
        ],

But I get:
SELECT failed: ERR invalid DB index [tcp://localhost:6379] {"userId":"7fb7038f-0ed4-46ff-9779-7c536a0efe8a","exception":"[object] (Predis\Connection\ConnectionException(code: 0): SELECT failed: ERR invalid DB index [tcp://localhost:6379] at /var/www/html
I installed predis using the command:
composer require predis/predis
And the command:
php artisan optimize:clear 
finishes with success.
Have you an idea about this issue?
